# Create SQL table from Post Request on a Form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I am trying to create a new table in a database each time a user submits a form. I take the information they submitted and use that to name the new table I create.
However when I query the database to make a new table, I get no response and the table is not made.
The SQL command I am submitting comes directly from when I manually made a table on PHPMyAdmin.

Ive checked to see if the post request was not getting through but it is, the problem has to be that it can't connect to the database, but I am able to connect to other databases in the system with the same credentials no problem.

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

$name = $_POST['user'];
$league = $_POST['league'];
$delim = '_';
$tablename =  $name . $delim . $league;

$s = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '$tablename' 
 ( `id` int(10) NOT NULL ,
  `title` VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL ,
  `description` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `position_order` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ";


$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);
echo $result;




?>
```

Output is always blank no table is created

Comment: check for errors https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Your error logs might also have useful information.

Comment: Error Log [15-May-2019 21:35:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/createtable.php on line 22

Comment: However not every request throws an error, I'm running it right now with no error but no table is being created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem, but Im not sure what the issue was.
I am now connecting but not choosing the database, then I updated my SQL command to

```
"CREATE TABLE `test`.`$tablename` ( `id` INT(10) NOT NULL , `title` VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL , `description` TEXT NOT NULL , `position_order` INT(11) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. if it doesn't work properly make sure your database connection working properly.

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

$name = $_POST['user'];
$league = $_POST['league'];
$delim = '_';
$tablename =  $name . $delim . $league;

$s = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '$tablename' 
(id int(10) NOT NULL ,
  title VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL ,
  description TEXT NOT NULL ,
  position_order INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";


$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);
echo $result;


?>
```